# unpack .mdf files from nested zip files

Tags: python, unzip

I have several zip files, with zip files inside these as well as other file types. I want to loop over the top level zips, identify the zips files in these, look inside these and extract the .mdf files.

I have the below code, but this only gets me to the point of extracting the nested zip files.

```
for file in os.listdir(working_directory):
    if zipfile.is_zipfile(file):
        with zipfile.ZipFile(file) as item:
            for member in item.namelist():  # go through members of the zip file
                if member.endswith('.zip'):
                    item.extract(member)    # extract only the mdf file
```

EDIT: Amended to this to get the inner .mdf file (but get error No such file or directory: 'test.zip':

```
for file in os.listdir(working_directory):
    if zipfile.is_zipfile(file):
        with zipfile.ZipFile(file) as item: 
            for member in item.namelist():  # go through members of the zip file
                if member.endswith('.zip'):
                    with zipfile.ZipFile(member) as item2: 
                        for member2 in item2.namelist(): 
                            if member2.endswith('.mdf'):
                                item2.extract(member2)
```

Tried adapting the below, but I'm not quite sure what its doing.

```
with zipfile.ZipFile('all.zip') as z:
    with z.open('nested.zip') as z2:
        z2_filedata =  io.BytesIO(z2.read())
        with zipfile.ZipFile(z2_filedata) as nested_zip:
            print( nested_zip.open('readme.md').read())
```

Comment: Better continue based on the first code snippet. "extract" returns the path to the extracted file which you can use to basically repeat the code beginning with the "with..." line, nested in the inner "if"-block. You can then find the ".mdf" files in the inner zip, extract them and finally close and (if wanted) delete the extracted zip-file.

Comment: Thank you. I tried something similar earlier (see above edit please) but got an error. I've read its something to do with the ```os```, which needs a certain requirement when inside the zip file. May have that wrong.

Comment: In the second code snippet you omitted the extraction of the zip-file from the first snippet.

Comment: That works thank you very much for your help. Feel free to add as an answer.